# How do I sort this list of dictionaries by the average of the key ratings 's value? without using imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

how do I Sort the input based on the average of the values in "ratings"? THis works

```
data = [{ "ratings":[3,4,5,2,1,5], "budget":3, "box_office":5},{ "ratings":[1,1,3,4,5,6], "budget":4, "box_office":90},{ "ratings":[5,4,3,2,1.6], "budget":45, "box_office":55},{ "ratings":[3,2,4,2,3,4], "budget":89, "box_office":56}]

def average_rating(cname):
    jim = cname['ratings']
    average = sum(jim)/len(jim)
    return average

def sort_by_average_rating(cname):
    cname.sort(key = average_rating)
    return cname
print(sort_by_average_rating(data))
```

Comment: please give us sample values to work on. Thanks.

Comment: It should be `key = average_rating`. The value of the `key` argument is a function, not the result of calling the function.

Comment: just want to understand how can i sort based on the average of the values inside the key ratings

Comment: `average = sum(jim)/len(jim)`, no need for a loop.

Comment: thanks @Barmar i was able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to get average rating and use [`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) parameter of sorted to sort based on that avg. ratings.

> Both `list.sort()` and `sorted()` have a key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons.

```
from statistics import mean
data = [{ "ratings":[3,4,5,2,1,5], "budget":3, "box_office":5},{ "ratings":[1,1,3,4,5,6], "budget":4, "box_office":90},{ "ratings":[5,4,3,2,1.6], "budget":45, "box_office":55},{ "ratings":[3,2,4,2,3,4], "budget":89, "box_office":56}]

sorted(data,key=lambda x:mean(x['ratings']))
# [{'ratings': [3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4], 'budget': 89, 'box_office': 56},
#  {'ratings': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1.6], 'budget': 45, 'box_office': 55},
#  {'ratings': [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5], 'budget': 3, 'box_office': 5},
#  {'ratings': [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'budget': 4, 'box_office': 90}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from statistics import mean

sorted(data, key=lambda x: mean(x['ratings']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from statistics import mean

data = [{ "ratings":[3,4,5,2,1,5], "budget":3, "box_office":5},{ "ratings":[1,1,3,4,5,6], "budget":4, "box_office":90},{ "ratings":[5,4,3,2,1.6], "budget":45, "box_office":55},{ "ratings":[3,2,4,2,3,4], "budget":89, "box_office":56}]

sorted(data, key=lambda x: mean(x['ratings']))
```

This should help.